# How do I create a process that checks date time and performs action when elapsed time passed?

Tags: c#, .net

in my dll I'm serializing an object that I need to expire, and regenerate when x amount of days have passed.
How can I do this in a way that doesn't require the calling application to restart every day (in order to initiate the check for date time in my dll)?

using .net 3.5

```
    private void updatePersistableItems()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Items_FILENAME) && PersistableItems != null) //create new
        {
            _serializer.SerializeObject<PersistableObject>(Items_FILENAME, PersistableItems);
        }
        else //check if expired and replace, or update if not expired
        {
            PersistableObject ItemsFromStorage = new PersistableObject();

            ItemsFromStorage = _serializer.DeSerializeObject<PersistableObject>(Items_FILENAME);

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - ItemsFromStorage.DateItemsInitialized;
            if (ts.TotalDays < this.DaysToPersistItems) //use stored Items
                Items = ItemsFromStorage.Items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the serialised object for? Could you just check it is fresh when you go to use it?

Comment: Show us your code, what have you attempted?

Comment: Why are you opposed to starting your application once a day.  that sounds like exactly the right solution.

Comment: @Servy I'm not in control of the calling application

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov added code, but it only works once, when I initialize my object

Answer (score 1):

Use a Timer to periodically call your function that does the checking: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That requires keeping the program running 24/7, when it'll be doing absolutely nothing 99.99% of the time.

Comment: @Servy the calling application is supposed to be running 24/7 so this solution just might work for me

Comment: actually, thanks for this, I did try it but found that the timer interval has restriction of max value of Int32 milliseconds.  I need it to run longer than that. (i.e. 90 days which is 7,776,000,000 milliseconds)

Comment: You don't have to run your function every time the timer stops, you can just check if you should run it (e.g. with DateTime comparison with the last run, etc), and do it or just start the timer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can start new Thread with while loop. Once executed on start of the application the thread can check the time amount left till content expiry, and go to sleep for the rest of the time. Once waked up after sleep, refresh content, calculate time amount left to sleep .... : )

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a the task scheduler which can be [controlled via c# this wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/). Using this you can schedule the update to get run even if your application is not running all the time.